What is the difference between AWS Amplify Gen 1 and Gen 2?
I have started to learn AWS Amplify out of curiosity and wanted to know the difference between Gen 1 and Gen 2. Although I was not able to find apple to apple comparison with respect to the syntax and new features. I would also like to ask what how I can get the list of registered users in my app?

Gen2 is TypeScript first framework, no CLI. For backend provisioning it uses CDK. There are a lot new things in Gen2 - Refer to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-amplify-gen2/
